# Automatically create group events at facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-events

Since the second version of the Graph API from Facebook they didn't allow anymore to create events via the API.

I want automatically create each 2 days a new event in a specific group. Is there another solution except to do it manually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it´s not possible to create events with the Graph API anymore, as you pointed out. You need to create events manually.

Comment: Basically this is a fact that i knew and described above, as you pointed out also. Is there another possibilities like via Facebook directly (webpage) to create events which are repeated (interval of X days)? :)